# convert windows javac command to linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, path, javac

I'm having troubles with converting my javac command as used under windows (my libraries are placed within the lib folder, the source code within the src folder, and the compiled code should be placed within the bin folder):

```
javac -cp lib/\* -d bin src/\*.java
```

into the correct linux javac command.  I have tried many variations including

```
javac -cp lib/* -d bin src/*.java
```

but that doesn't seem to work :

> "**invalid flag: lib/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar**".

I am looking for a solution to this already quite some time, so any advice on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you are using JDK7/8, are you running javac from that folder?

Comment: Yes, I'm using JDK8 and running the commands in the folder which has src, bin and lib as subfolders.  The listed javac command in Windows is working, I'm actually looking for the similar command in Linux.

Comment: It should work fine unless you have more classpath arguments than you are listing. In that case you would need to change all your `:`s to `;`s

Comment: Are there any spaces in the names of your libs/folders?

Comment: I've edited the "invalid flag" outcome into a more specific one ... Internet searches suggested that it had something to do with incorrect path formulations ??  I assume that I am running a recent JDK version, as I am working on a recently downloaded raspbian distribution ...

Comment: try putting lib/* in quotes "lib/*"

Comment: OK, thanks a lot ... this seems to be working as the code is compiled without any errors!

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll put that as the answer then and this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Yes, the issue was solved ... 
Do you know perhaps how the java equivalent works as well... java cp ../lib/* MainClass does not work, also when I'm adding quotes ...

Comment: What is the message it gives you?

Comment: without quotes: could not find or load main class
with quotes: command not found

Comment: found it: I should replace ; by :

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those odd things that happens when you don't put quotes around an argument.

Solution worked out in comments section: "lib/*" instead of lib/*

```
javac -cp "lib/*" -d bin src/*.java
```

The other issue was that `;` is needed instead of `:` in Linux for classpaths.